# Error adding variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell

When I run the following bash script:

```
Success: $(grep success * | grep B2B | wc -l)
etc_error: $(grep etc_error * | grep B2B | wc -l)
map_timeout: $(grep map_timeout * | grep B2B | wc -l)

success=$(grep success * | grep B2B | wc -l)
etc=$(grep etc_error * | grep B2B | wc -l)
map=$(grep map_timeout * | grep B2B | wc -l)

sum=$(($success + $etc + $map))
total=$(($success / $sum))
echo $total
```

I got the error:

```
-bash: + + : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+ ")
```

What is wrong with my script?

Comment: The first three lines ought to give you `Command not found` errors in `bash`, unless you have scripts called `Success:`, `etc_error:` and `map_timeout:` in your `PATH`.

Comment: Either you're not showing the full script or you're not showing the full error messages. Try also running with `bash -x` to see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn’t explain everything — given your variable declarations, they should have a value — but since you’re using [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html#Arithmetic-Expansion), you don’t need `$` to introduce variables; undefined variables then default to 0:

```
sum=$((success + etc + map))
total=$((success / sum))
echo "$total"
```

Ideally you should check that `sum` is non-zero before dividing, but at least you’ll get a sensible error message with this approach even if you don’t check `sum` (“division by 0” rather than “syntax error: operand expected”, in bash).

The error you’re getting comes from

```
sum=$(($success + $etc + $map))
```

For some reason, `success`, `etc` and `map` are all undefined or empty. The shell expands the above to

```
sum=$(( + + ))
```

and then tries to expand that, which results in the syntax error you quote.

This is rather surprising though since

```
success=$(grep success * | grep B2B | wc -l)
```

should produce a value...

BTW, You may want to improve the above to:

```
success=$(grep success ./* | grep -c B2B)
```

or, if `B2B` is to be matched on the content of the *success* lines and not on the file names:

```
success=$(cat ./* | grep success | grep -c B2B)
```

or with GNU `grep` or compatible:

```
success=$(grep -h success ./* | grep -c B2B)
```

Comment: of course if you default to zero mathematics forbid dividing by zero :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to check your variables before the addition, because if one of then is not set or has no numeric value
the addition syntax will fail

you can defaulty set vars to 0 before setting then to avoid that.

Comment: What do you mean check variables before addition? Can you give some examples? Thanks!

Comment: @Cyril Basic debugging: Output the values of the variables so that you can inspect them and see whether they are what you expect them to be.